# Facebook C# SDK 4.2.1 posting on wall problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0

Hello i have a problem when i try to post something on users wall. here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
        app = new FacebookApp();
        auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(app);
    auth.Perms += "user_about_me,publish_stream,create_event,offline_access";
    if (auth.IsAuthorized())
    {
        Response.Write("authorized    " + app.Session.UserId.ToString()+"  "+app.Session.AccessToken + "<br/>");
        dynamic rez = app.Get("me");
        Response.Write(rez.first_name + "  "+rez.last_name);
    }
    else
        Response.Write("not authorized    ");      
}
protected void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
    parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html";
    parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg";
    parameters.name = "Article Title";
    parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";
    parameters.description = "Longer description of the link";
    parameters.actions = new
    {
        name = "View on Zombo",
        link = "http://www.zombo.com",
    };
    parameters.privacy = new
    {
        value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
    };
    parameters.targeting = new
    {
        countries = "US",
        regions = "6,53",
        locales = "6",
    };
    dynamic result = app.Api("/me/feed",parameters);
}
```

when i try to post i get the :

(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

P.S.

```
dynamic rez = app.Get("me");
        Response.Write(rez.first_name + "  "+rez.last_name);
```

is working with no problems!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have not given it access token try putting

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp("my_access_token");
```

at top of post button event and replace

```
dynamic result = app.Api("/me/feed",parameters);
```

with

```
dynamic result = app.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: should it be just like this: 
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp("my_access_token"); 
or instead of "my_access_token" should be some kind of string that is access token, like "123csdre23324324...." ?

Comment: add settings file from solution explorer that will give you file that can have some values in it declare a string type field id then all you have to do is FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp(settingFile.Default.id);

Comment: settings file enables consistency of data we can update from one or more places in code

Comment: you can also directly put your Application Token as you said

Comment: Can you tell me please how to get the access token?

Comment: download the facebook sdk c# from codeplex and see the example files